# Connect socket browser to android socket using nodejs (browser using nodejs javascript)

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

i have use node js and android, my application running live chess in web browser and in android side use in webview but i have connect simple start button event in android to start using node js socket **(Ex. Emite Event in android and lessen event in web browser in node js)**.